# Javascript Popup Window

Tags: javascript, popup

I have used a ton of javascript popup windows over the years, any recommendations on the best one out there?

I would like to see if there are better ways to do popups.

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3602935/best-pop-up-box-plug-in-of-jquery

Answer (score 2):

Eric Martin's [SimpleModal](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/) plug-in is quite nice and easy to use.

Answer (score 1):

[QTip](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/)'s really nice, its a Jquery based library that has a really clean look to it

I have also used Jquery Dialog, but find that QTip has some really nice features (see the images and stuff)

I had a very strange bug with Qtip the other day and the creator got back to me within twenty minutes of my git post and helped me debug it.

Good support, Great product

Answer (score 1):

[jQuery dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) is quite good.

Answer (score 0):

Extremely Lightweight Modal popup plugin.
POPELT - http://welbour.com/labs/popelt/

It is lightweight, supports nested popups, object oriented, supports dynamic buttons, responsive, and lot more.
Next update will include Popup Ajax form submissions etc.

Feel free to use and tweet feedback.

Answer (score 0):

jsframe.js - https://github.com/riversun/JSFrame.js

It's lightweight popup window library for javascript.