# best Pop-up box plug-in of jquery 

Tags: jquery, plugins, popup

i use facebox.js  to pop-up div on my site ,

but i don't think it is the best one ,

so  what plug-in of jquery are you using for pop-up ,

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean modal window pop ups because you mention facebox.

There are many and it really depends on what your needs are. However I would recommend these:

- [jqModal](http://dev.iceburg.net/jquery/jqModal/) - AJAX, many configuration options, true modal (locks keyboard within modal)
- [Soh Tanaka's simple modal popups.](http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/inline-modal-window-w-css-and-jquery/) - Inline, simple

Answer (score 1):

jQModal is nice.

**[BlockUI](http://jquery.malsup.com/block/)** can do modal dialogs, in addition to custom element blocking.
Also have a look at **[SimpleModal](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/)**, which offers lots of options as well.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want to take a look at http://planetozh.com/projects/lightbox-clones/ and compare the features of almost every lightbox against each other.

Comment: this is the page you show your boss to explain why it's taken you a whole day to make a popup

Answer (score 0):

There's no best one. There are different plugins which might fit your needs (which you didn't expose). To name a few:

- [jQuery dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/)
- [jQuery SimpleTip](http://craigsworks.com/projects/simpletip/)
- [jQuery qTip](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/)

Personally I have used `simpleTip` for showing AJAX popups when hovering over certain regions.